# I can't binding DataGrid to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I can't understand what's happening here. I have two public properties in my ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<vw_ClientesFull> MyClients { get; set; }

private IEnumerable<vw_ClientesFull> _clients;
public IEnumerable<vw_ClientesFull> Clients
        {
            get
            {
                return _clients;
            }
            set
            {
                _clients= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Clients");
            }
        }
```

Then I have a method to refresh both of them:

```
private void RefreshClientes()
    {
        this.serviceClient.Clientes_ListarCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {                
            Clients = e.Result;
            MyClients = new ObservableCollection<vw_ClientesFull>(Clients);
        };            
        this.serviceClient.Clientes_ListarAsync(_sRazonSocial, VendedorSel, TransporteSel, _nID, bInactivos);
    }
```

Them i bind my dataGrid to show the information. If I do:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Clients}"
```

If works perfect, but if i do:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyClients}"
```

**Nothing is show! Why? Doesn't ObservableCollection fire onPropertyChange Automaticaly?**

Thanks for the help!!!

**UPDATE**

So if i need to fire the OnPropertyChange manualy, why this work without it?

```
public ObservableCollection<Vendedores> Vendedores { get; set; }

private void CargarVendedores()
    {        
        Vendedores = new ObservableCollection<Vendedores>(this.serviceClient.GetVendedores());                           
        this.VendedorSel = this.Vendedores.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

If i bind a combobox like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Vendedores}"
```

Work without the OnPropertyChange! Why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ObservableCollection implements INotifyPropretyChanged. However, it isn't going to help you here :)

ObservableCollection is special because it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. In other words, it raises an event when items are added to or removed from the underlying collection. It also implements INotifyPropertyChanged, so anything bound to a property of the collection will get updated.

You are changing the variable itself though (setting to a new instance no less). This requires that the "instance" of the ObservableCollection **property** raise the event. In other words, you need:

```
private ObservableCollection<vw_ClientesFull> myClients;
public ObservableCollection<vw_ClientesFull> MyClients 
{ 
    get { return myClients; }
    set
    {
       myClients = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("MyClients"); 
}
```

In your update, the binding hasn't fired yet (you set in the constructor) so it gets the correct list. Subsequent changes to the list wouldn't work, however.

Comment: Excelent Answer like always. So I suppose there's no point on using ObservableColection instead of IENumerable, as i need all the code anyway.

Comment: As far as explicitly saying you are binding to an ObservableCollection (by forcing it to be that type), no it doesn't gain you much in functionality. The only thing you gain is you won't be able to accidentally assign a List or other simple collection (and thus lose the CollectionChanged event)

Comment: Ok. My only intent was to have less and more readble code, but if i need anyway to do the onpropertychange the code is the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This problem is due to a misconception. ObservableCollection does *not* raise PropertyChanged, (which happens when the entire property is reassigned) when you replace it, but rather CollectionChanged (which is raised when items are added or removed). You still need to raise PropertyChanged if you plan to reassign the whole object.

Comment: Actually it does, but not when the holding property itself changes (so you are mostly right) :)

Comment: In your second case, the value is assigned before leaving the constructor, so it already has a value when the binding is formed. @LordTakkera: Fixed! Now it says when reassigned, which is what I meant.

Comment: It could still probably be a little clearer, but I appreciate your edit. +1!

Answer (score 1):

You must raise the `PropertyChanged` event when you set the value of `MyClients`, same as you've already done for `Clients`.

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't ObservableCollection do this automaticaly when the collection change? See my update please

Comment: No. An `ObservableCollection` instance raises `NotifyPropertyChanged` and `NotifyCollectionChanged` from the collection itself. You have to manually raise `PropertyChanged` from the containing class when the property changes. An `ObservableCollection` knows only about itself. It doesn't know the property it's stored in.

Comment: That comment should be part of the answer, as it gets to the heart of the problem.